# Por quê não consigo apagar um objeto com o Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu tenho em uma tela uma tabela de processos e quero apagar um deles. Este é um pedaço do meu **datatable**:

```
<p:column headerText="Excluir" style="width:68px">
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{processoMB.excluir(obj)}"
        icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" styleClass="btn btn-block"
        update=":frmTabela :dlgInformacao" alt="Excluir">
        <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir?" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Este é meu método **excluir(Processo processo)**:

```
public void excluir(Processo processo) {
    try {
        daoProcesso.remover(processo);
        ExibirMensagem.exibirMensagem(Mensagem.SUCESSO);
        operacoesDeAlteracao();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExibirMensagem.exibirMensagem(Mensagem.ERRO);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

E este é meu método **remover(T objeto)** no GenericDAO

```
public void remover(T objeto) {
    Object  o = manager.merge(objeto);
    manager.remove(o);
}
```

Quando clico no botão para excluir um processo o Hibernate faz apenas estas operações e não exclui meu objeto processo:

```
Hibernate: select processo0_.id_processo as id_proce1_0_0_, processo0_.descricao as descrica2_0_0_ from tab_processo processo0_ where processo0_.id_processo=?
Hibernate: select processo0_.id_processo as id_proce1_0_, processo0_.descricao as descrica2_0_ from tab_processo processo0_ where id_processo<>0
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Selecione o objeto depois use `remove`. Não esqueça de abrir e fechar uma transação.

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi como selecionar um objeto, dá uma olhada na linha 44 e 45 [desse código](https://gist.github.com/jamilsonjunior/c9b5af8a399cf45263889a0ee8fc5f1e) pra ver se eu fiz direito. Quanto a abrir e fechar a transação isto está sendo feito por um interceptor com CDI.

Comment: Seria mais ou menos assim ´Object o = manager.find(Object.class, id)`. Eu uso CDI e no DAO eu uso a annotation `@Transacional`.

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas continua não funcionando. [Esse](https://gist.github.com/jamilsonjunior/c9b5af8a399cf45263889a0ee8fc5f1e#file-genericdao-java-L23) é o novo método que eu criei.

Comment: Posta um método que existe e que funciona para podermos comparar. Neste seu caso se você passa o objeto como parâmetro, acredito não ser necessário `manager.merge`. Poderia usar o método `remove`' diretamente. Eu uso a implementação "weld" e criei uma classe para auxiliar as transações e utilizo a anotação `@Transaction` em cada método que atualiza ou remove objetos do BD.

Comment: Já que você está efetuando uma alteração em uma linha do banco é necessário abrir a transação e após a alteração commitar a alteração. Onde você faz isso?

Comment: Pode não ter muito a ver.. Mas vale tentar: ao invés de fazer `Object  o` tente fazer `T o`.

Comment: @MarceloGomes Eu ainda não entendo muito bem como o CDI funciona, mas eu tinha uma classe no meu projeto chamada `Transacional`. Eu coloquei a anotação `@Transacional` no meu método `remover(Class<T> classe, Long id)` e agora eu finalmente consigo excluir objetos.

Comment: Vou adicionar esta resposta e vc marca como a resposta correta. Quem bom que deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando CDI você deve anotar o método no DAO ou Service, dependendo de sua estratégia:

```
@Transacional 
public void excluir(Processo processo) {
    try {
        daoProcesso.remover(processo);
        ExibirMensagem.exibirMensagem(Mensagem.SUCESSO);
        operacoesDeAlteracao();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExibirMensagem.exibirMensagem(Mensagem.ERRO);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {

           public void remover(T objeto) {
            manager.getTransaction().begin() ;
            Object  o = manager.merge(objeto);
            manager.remove(o);
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
         }

 } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();                          
    manager.getTransaction().rollback();                         
 }
```

Você pode tentar outra opção!

```
manager.remove( manager.find(seuObjeto.class, id) );
```

Se a outra opção não funcionar tenta a sim! se você tiver um método que busca por **id** você pode usar ele para substituir o **manager.find().**